# Tortoise Versioning - does it REALLY matter?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Other than the fact that each version of Tortoise svn typically adds new features or changes up some ways to do things to improve the process...I don't see any problem with using the latest.  I've worked for .coms, small, and huge companies and nobody has ever worried about this.

Now if you're new and you're trying to stick with what the team has, because in case any instructions go out to help you then you might want to stick with whatever the rest of the team is using.

For me, I'm very comfortable with Tortoise.  It's no big deal for me to figure out how to do the same way as an older version in a newer version if that particular functionality has changed.

However I'm wondering...or I assume basically that the underlying repository (Subversion) is always going to be consistent.  That using x version of tortoise svn won't matter in terms of meta data being stored, etc.

Is this a correct assumption and if so where did you find info on that because I haven't seen anything that really talks about this.

Comment: It matters because it avoids the annoying "get update" popups :( No, really, TSVN should be kept updated. The feature changes are about nil, but there have been a number of issues addressed (and don't even think about running an old-old client on a newer repo). The weekly updates are sometimes annoying, but the change log explains what the update is about.

Comment: I don't really care about pop-ups

Comment: http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#multiclients.  Ok in here it states "But you can only use different clients if they all use the same version of the Subversion library. The version of the Subversion library that TortoiseSVN uses is indicated in the filename of the installer, other clients have similar indications. You have to make sure that those versions match each other in the first two digits. For example, all clients using Subversion 1.6.x can be used together (the 'x' indicates that this number is not relevant for compatibility)."

Comment: but I know I've had people on the team just use whatever version and we've never had a problem...so I don't see WHY they say this.  They don't explain why.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: when that says "together", that means "against the same working copy". The *server* is much more forgiving, but you should keep your client up to date anyway.

Comment: hmm thanks.  I guess I don't get it.  So if you have a working copy that you're working locally, you're only going to have one client on your machine...the client you're using.

Comment: You can install more than one client. Maybe not more than one of Tortoise itself because it only lets you install one of it, but you could install a different version of the standard Subversion command line tools. Or, you could store your working copy on a network drive and access it from more than one computer (but hopefully not at the same time!).

Answer (score 4):

the problem is not if someone else uses your working copy, but if you use a different client. In this case the newer client would upgrade the working copy format and the older one would then by unable to access it.

I upgraded Tortoise once and suddenly my Ankhsvn client refused to work - as the WC had been upgraded to 1.6 by Tortoise, but Ankh hadn't yet been recompiled to work with svn 1.6. The opposite would hold true too. You may think this is not an issue you'll ever come across (maybe so), but sometimes you will want a security fix or update and then it will matter.

I would recommend upgrading every time a new tortoise comes out - the point versions are very backwards compatible and even if there was a problem you can just downgrade it without problem. You will want the new version when subversion 1.7 is released so upgrade then too. (I read the occasional post here about people running svn 1.4 or older, you don't want to be them - upgrade, the subversion team is very good about backwards compatibility and painless upgrades, but upgrading 3 or 4 versions up isn't going to be as painless as upgrading 1 major version).

Comment: what do you mean by different client?  OS?

Comment: different clients. eg TortoiseSVN is 1 client, AnkhSVN is another. Collabnet's svn command line tools another.

Answer (score 3):

What matters in terms of collaboration is not Tortoise (the shell), but Subversion itself (the core). For example, let's assume that you have some working copies that might be used by more than one developer, possibly using more than one SVN client. If such a working copy is still in 1.5 format and you touch it with a 1.6 client (and perform some non-trivial operation), it'll automatically upgrade the working copy to 1.6 format, rendering it uselell for 1.5 clients. See [Subversion 1.6 Release Notes - Working Copy and Repository Filesystem Format Changes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html). (Of course, you should avoid shared working copies, but that's a different story.)

Comment: I guess I still don't get it.  A working copy is a download of the branch or whatever to your local drive that you work on.  Why would anyone else be pointed to your local working copy?

Comment: Common example is an IDE like Eclipse which has its own subversion libraries.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Perhaps an analogous example can clarify. Assume your team uses Visual Studio 2008. (Substitute anything you like for VS here where the new version is not backward compatible.) Now you upgrade to VS2010. Once you have opened the VS2008 project in VS2010, it is converted to a format that is no longer compatible with VS2008. When you check that in _none of your team members can use the project unless they upgrade also_!

A new Subversion client _may_ introduce similar breaking changes to the repository data; so it is repository changes, not your local copy, to be concerned with.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - I've seen working copies shared by multiple developers in action on staging servers. No, it is not good practice at all, and yes, it should be avoided. Regardless of this special case (which is not too frequent, I guess), you can also inadvertently upgrade your own working copy, as others have pointed out, by using another client, of which there are many (Tortoise, command line, Cygwin, Eclipse, Ant - they can all bring their own client).